# XHR formdata ionic application

Tags: javascript, android, ionic4, capacitor

I have a weird act with xhr -> form-data:

I develop an Ionic application that complied to Android & IOS.

I'm trying to upload a file using blob and formdata xhr and the act is:

IOS - works great.

Android - works great in some Android versions, but devices such as LG & Xiaomi aren't response at all.

here is my code:

```js
const uploadInvoice = async(data, type = "expenses", file, cb) => {
  if (type === "incomes") {
    delete data.budget;
  }
  data.invoicedate = data.date;
  data.title = encodeURI(data.title);
  const formData = new FormData();
  const extention = file.name.split(".").pop();
  const newFileModified = new File(
    [file],
    `${Date.now().toString()}.${extention}`
  );
  formData.append("file", newFileModified);
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", `${BASE_URL}/api/management/file`);
  Object.keys(data).map(key => {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(key, data[key]);
  });
  xhr.setRequestHeader("client", "app");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      //if complete
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        return cb(true);
      } else {
        return cb(false); //otherwise, some other code was returned
      }
    } else {
      return cb(false);
    }
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
};
```

note that I dispatch http request (and not https) but I have the right permissions to upload an http request.

I went over the internet to find a solution without success :-/

thanks!!

Comment: "devices such as LG & Xiaomi" does not suffice to identify the problem... that's an error description just alike "it's not working". Which devices are these, which API levels? Ever tried running an AVD at the same API level?

Comment: I think that the common ground between them is the Android version: "9 pie", actually I don't get any response.

Comment: Android 9+ blocks http by default, search for enabling clear text